# Problema con JQuery Toast Message, no me muestra mensajes

Tags: jquery, plugin

estoy intentado implementar un sistema de **notificaciones** en mi pagina web, y para ello estoy usando el siguiente [plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Highly-Customizable-jQuery-Toast-Message-Plugin-Toastr.html).

Lo primero que hice fue **descargar** el plugin, y lo inserte en mi **directorio:** `../static/notificaciones` como muestro a continuacion:

[image: Imagen del directorio de mi web]

Como se puede apreciar el `dir` padre es **WIKI FAMILIA**.

Le cambie el nombre del `.zip` del plugin (lo llame **notificaciones**) para que asi fuese mas comodo **importarlo**.

Bueno pues para hacer un test he creado un `testing.php` en este **directorio:** `WIKI FAMILIA/testing.php`, el cual, esta de la sigiente manera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <!-- TOASTR.CSS DEL PLUGIN -->
    <link href="static/notificaciones/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="static/notificaciones/toastr.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Testing</h1>
                <button id="miBoton" class="btn btn-info" click>Float message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <script
                  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
                  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
                  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script
                  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
                  integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
                  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        $("#miBoton").click(function() {

            toastr.warning('Warning');


        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

He tenido que hacer eso porque no me funciona y estoy probando a ver porque. En este fichero `testing.php` simplemente lo que he hecho ha sido crear un boton y hacer que cuando pulse salga un toaster warning de la forma mas simple posible, pues no me lo hace. No se porque. ¿Alguien ha tenido un problema parecido con esto?

Comment: Para cualquier plugin que necesite `jquery` primero debes cargar `jquery` y luego el plugin. Tal como lo indicaron en la respuesta. Incluso así lo hacen acá [https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Highly-Customizable-jQuery-Toast-Message-Plugin-Toastr.html](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Highly-Customizable-jQuery-Toast-Message-Plugin-Toastr.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te pongo un ejemplo sencillo de manejo del plugin. El problema que le veo a tu código es el orden de carga de las librerías. El plugin `toastr` necesita tener cargada primero la librería de `Jquery` para poder inicializarse, en tu caso cargas primero los **JS** de `toastr` y después los de **Jquery**.

Otro problema que puedes tener es que no estés referenciando bien la localización del directorio donde tienes el plugin.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <a id='linkButton'>ClickMe</a>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/js/toastr.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    toastr.options.timeOut = 1500; // 1.5s
    toastr.info('Page Loaded!');
    $('#linkButton').click(function() {
       toastr.success('Click Button');
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Referencia:** [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22191363/10268956)

**Ejemplo con código de la pregunta**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Testing</h1>
          <button id="miBoton" class="btn btn-info" click>Float message</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/js/toastr.js"></script>    

    <script>
      $("#miBoton").click(function() {
        toastr.warning('Warning');
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Editado para añadir un ejemplo funcionando con el código de la pregunta. Lo único que hice fue cargar las librerías en el orden correcto y usar enlaces en la nube para cargar las librerías del `toastr` y así confirmar que el error posiblemente esté en la referencia al directorio del plugin.

Comment: Muchas gracias @phpMyGuel , pues por alguna razon no me funciona descargando la libreria y ejecutandola desde local. Por otra parte, no encontre yo el cdn de la libreria, por eso fue uno de los motivos por el cual lo descargue en local. Sin mas, muy agradecido.